# Simple image gallery with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, image-gallery, samsung-mobile

I'm writing an image gallery with horizontal scrolling. Images must be added programatically. 
I use a custom horizontal scroll view to process and add images as in the following code:

```
    public void setViewList(Integer linearLayoutId, Integer[] imageIdList,
                            Activity activity) {

    displayMetrics = ImageUtils.getDisplayMetric(activity);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(linearLayoutId);
    for (Integer imgId : imageIdList) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());

        imageView.setImageResource(imgId);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

        Integer[] displayMetrics = ImageUtils.getDisplayMetric(activity);
        ImageUtils.scaleImage(imageView, displayMetrics[0], displayMetrics[1]);

        Integer[] dstDimension = ImageUtils.createDimension();
        ImageUtils.getImageSize(imageView, dstDimension);
        getImageSizeList().add(dstDimension);

        ll.addView(imageView);
    }

}
```

As you can see I scale an image with use the following method (call `ImageUtils.scaleImage(imageView, displayMetrics[0], displayMetrics[1])`):

```
    public static void scaleImage(ImageView imView, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
    Drawable temp = imView.getDrawable();

    Bitmap imBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)temp).getBitmap();

    int imWidth = imBitmap.getWidth();
    int imHeight = imBitmap.getHeight();

    float xScale = ((float) screenWidth) / imWidth;
    float yScale = ((float) screenHeight) / imHeight;

    float scale = xScale <= yScale ? xScale : yScale;
    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);

    Bitmap scBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imBitmap, 0, 0, imWidth, imHeight, scaleMatrix, true);

    BitmapDrawable scDrBitmap = new BitmapDrawable(imView.getResources(), scBitmap);
    imView.setImageDrawable(scDrBitmap);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    imView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

My main.xml layout is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.lessons.custom_horizontal_scroll.CustomHorizontalScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.lessons.custom_horizontal_scroll.CustomHorizontalScrollView>
```

Where the android.lessons.custom_horizontal_scroll.CustomHorizontalScrollView is implementation of a simple custom HorizontalScrollView.

For testing I use Samsung Galaxy S3 and images with the following resolution: (1) 1290*990 (2) 1221*900. What it looks like:

[image]

In many cases everything is displayed fine but from time to time I get the wrong result: the first image divides a screen with the following one at app start time and I don't have any idea why it happens.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) from the support library v4 rather than this custom horizontal scroll view in this case. It's designed for that purpose.

Here is how to use it https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html.

Comment: Yeah! That works. Thanks a lot. But the question stays opened :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved with use gravity = Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, that i set programmatically on a image view (method ImageUtils.scaleImage).